# Next.js Google Analytics with ReactGA

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Hi there i'm using ReactGA4 for track my Analytics in Next app. I am facing the issue that i cant see the path where the user is until they reload the page. This is my code.

```
ReactGA.initialize("UA-xxxxxxx");
ReactGA.send("pageview");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscribe to the `Router` `events` and use the GA `pageview` interface.

Remember to use the `routeChangeComplete` which will send the pageview via the ReactGA method

Modified [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#usage-6) example

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleRouteChange = (url, { shallow }) => {
      // REACTGA
      // Send pageview with a custom path
      ReactGA.send({ hitType: "pageview", page: "/my-path" });
      console.log(`App is changing to ${url} ${shallow ? "with" : "without"} shallow routing`);
    };

    router.events.on("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);

    // If the component is unmounted, unsubscribe
    // from the event with the `off` method:
    return () => {
      router.events.off("routeChangeComplete", handleRouteChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Comment: So i put ReactGA.initialize("UA-xxxxxxx") before the ReactGA.send({ hitType: "pageview", page: "/my-path" })...? Thanks in advance. I am working with react cookies consent too so the code its a bit messy

Comment: Yes, initialize before - The router code subscribes to the soft navigation.

Comment: Thanks so much It works like charm!!

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted!

Comment: Any thoughts on having the `useEffect` with no deps? If `router.events` changes, it won't ever update?